# MySql error when running my .net application on linux server

Tags: mysql

I tested my application on windows environment and it works fine. I have it set up on a remote linux server and suddenly I started getting the following error with one of the APIs while all the others work fine:

> MySql.Data.dll Error : 0 : Unable to connect to any of the specif
>   ied MySQL hosts. MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to
>   connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

any hint on why this could happen, connection settings are the same and nothing changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mySQL Exception: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. through C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868784/mysql-exception-unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts-through)

Comment: Please just check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962923/unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts-when-checking-connection and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618720/unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts. Have same issue like you