# MySQL Connection with C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a code written in JAVA:

```
String host = "jdbc:mysql://online/find";
String username = "test";
String password = "test";
```

And its working fine. But I want to use the same database MySQL with C#. And I am doing this:

```
try
{

string myConnStr = "Server=//online/find; " +
                  " Port = 3306; "+
                  " DATABASE=finder; " + 
                  " UID=test;Password=test;";

MySqlConnection MySqlConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnStr);

MySqlDataAdapter MySqlAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

MySqlAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select * from finder.Customer", MySqlConn);

MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(MySqlAdapter);

MySqlConn.Open();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

MessageBox.Show("Connected");

MySqlConn.Close();

}
```

But I am getting Error:

```
Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts
```

I even tried with
IP address in connection string but still its not working.

I have checked these posts already:

[Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts. C# MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993657/unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts-c-sharp-mysql)

[unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts. c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365192/unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts-c-sharp)

Comment: Why on Earth are you concatenating your connection string?!

Comment: @Brandon I tried without concatenation, but still the same error!

Comment: Based on the documentation, are you sure that `" UID=test;Password=test;";` are correct?  From what I read, it should be `Uid=` and `Pwd=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first idea about the issue is "this has nothing to do with param names for username and password". You are not getting an error like:

> user "null" cant login

Java and C# work on totally different foundation (Oracle vs. Microsoft) I don't know Java but I think the libraries for connecting to a remote location must be different.

I think the host URL you used is the problem:

> Server=//online/find;

I use MySQL with my C# projects and I define the host value as:

- localhost or 127.0.0.1
- an IP address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
- a host url (my.dbserver.com)

here is a working MySQL connection string:

```
<add name="dbConnNews"
connectionString="server=xx.xx.xx.xx;database=yyyyy;User
Id=zzzzzz;Password=**********;"
providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection.html) should be:

```
string myConnStr = 
"Database=finder;Data Source=//online/find;Port=3306;User Id=test;Password=test";
```

---

**However** for me Connection strings could be hard to remember.
Its very easy to make a mistake when you write it manually. 
One advice is to use the server explorer to connect to your database. Then right click on your database icon > select properties ... you will see the connection string copy and paste .
 Voilà!

**Server Explorer:**

[image]

**Properties:**

[image]

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012, Windows Form Application.

Comment: @Kami so?? but try `"Database=finder;Data Source=//online/find;Port=3306;User Id=test;Password=test"` first, if it didnt work then use the wizard

Comment: @Kami please use the wizard, this will avoid problems, it should be in vs 2012 as well

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the MySQl Connector for Microsoft Application? If yes then add a reference to MySql.dll from your C# application, then use the below connection string:

```
string myConnStr = "server=yourMySqlServerHostorIP; port=MySqlPort;uid=username;pwd=password;initial catalog=dbname";
```

To download mysql connector go to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/.

Answer (score 0):

Try to  connect to the server via IDE Server Explorer --> Data Connections and observe the connection string generated.