# Access mysql data through SSH tunnel using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, ssh, sqlyog

I have MySQL database at cloud which can be accessed using SSH tunnel. however i am using c# to connect to the database. i also installed SQL connector for visual studio as well.

Here are the steps i followed.

1. Installed `SQLYog` for SSH client.
2. tried to connect through`SQLYog`. **`connection successful`**.
3. tried to connect from c#. **`connection unsuccessful`**.

   Code :

   ```
      MySqlConnection myConn;

      string connStr = "server=localhost;user id=xxxxxxx;password=xxxxxxx;port=3306;persistsecurityinfo=False;";

      myConn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

      myConn.Open();
   ```

   Exception :

   **`Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL host.`**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655669/unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts) or [hosts file problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868784/mysql-exception-unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts-through)

Comment: If you decide to evaluate dotConnect for MySQL, refer to our documentation: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/SecureConnections.html#usessh . The SSH support is available in Standard / Professional / Developer editions: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/editions.html .

Comment: @Devart thanks for your answer. however i tried it in a different way like first i connect through SSH using putty on port 3306 than i exec queries through mysql library.